# clockgen – changed RAM speed in BIOS – no POST, dg41cn, E2180 Intel

Tags: cpu

My desktop computer uses an Intel dg41cn motherboard with a E2180 processor and 1 GB of RAM.

I tried to raise the processor frequency (GHz) and the system restarted. I then went to the BIOS. In the BIOS I changed the RAM speed (actually underclocked in BIOS to lesser speed) — it was altered already (5334 or something like that). Now the system continuously restarts without POSTing (or without entering the BIOS).

I have already tried the jumper/CMOS removal, and using RAM from another system, but nothing is working. I have no idea what to do now. I suspect the CPU is gone, or it's the motherboard. I first switched on the system without a ram, and it gave me three beeps. Now when I put the RAM in, the system goes about its restarting cycle. Can someone help me?

Comment: If you put in a single module do you get any screen output?

Comment: u mean the ram,i hav put another pc,s ram 1gb also,same cycle repeats,seriously its very frustrating,,thers jus no solution for this in intel,ther are others with intel dg boards who suffer after toughing the bios

Comment: That it doesn't reset whatever setting after you've done a CMOS reset is kind of strange. What's indicating that it's rebooting? And do you get output on your screen or not?

Comment: thank u sir for replyin,no output,the green light is on in mobo,with the ram,cpu n fan ,monitor,the sytem when on-it will start,no beep,nothing,the fans spin both the psu,cpu fan,both fans will stop for a second,n again start n stop this will be reapeatin for ever

Comment: today i tried ,burning a .bio file of my mobo in a dvd,i removed the jumper,connected the dvd rom,n the monitor,n on the pc,same on/off cycle-nothin on screen..,second try-i removed the ram,dvd n monitor connected,on the pc-three beeps came for no ram/the dvd rom spins,after some 10 or few three beeps,the system shutdown itself,i again turned the sys on removing the dvd rom,put the jumper in normal,did not connect the hard drive,put the ram now,now its same on/off cycle,does the ram slot gone bad?

Comment: That would one possibility. You probably fried one of the components (at least). It's hard to figure out which. The best approach would be to insert the CPU into another compatible Mobo and test whenever it works. If it does its the Mobo that's fried if it doesn't it would be the CPU. It's pretty strange that you're not getting any output at all. With that I'd probably try to send in the Mobo for a replacement.

Comment: thanks,i removed the cpu,and switch on the pc,no beeps nothing,ram was seated,dvd rom connected,monitor was conected,the fans were spinning ,dvd rom were spinning,i too think the cpu is fried..i am thinkin of buyin a mobo first from aliexpress,to try the cpu first and ram too.another thing i want to say-when i put the cpu with out cpu fan (i mean i did not place the connected cpu fan on the cpu),without ram i poweren on -till the sys shut down giving the ram beeps(wen not connected),-whilst i tried the bios recovery from dvd rom,a music like beep code came-it was for cpu heat-it seems

Comment: the beep code was like a music-alternating beeeeep beep beeeeep

Comment: Modern CPUs do have safeties in place but you should never run a CPU deliberately without a cooler. There should be a table or similar in your manual for the mainboard that would tell you what they mean.

Comment: i am thinkin of buying asus mobo refurbished one-p5ql pro,p5ql/epu,p5qlse,p5kplamse--wat do u think-these are lga775 as i want to check my e2180 processor too